# Bluebird PromisifyAll on Backbone not resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, promise, bluebird

Particularly  i want to promisify model.fetch method, so when I'm creating model I promisifying Backbone

```js
function (_, Backbone, Promise) {
  Backbone = Promise.promisifyAll(Backbone);
  var Diagram = Backbone.Model.extend({...});
}
```

But later I'm trying to use fetchAsync, on my diagram model and nothing happens.

```
diagram.fetchAsync()
   .then(function() {
     console.log('success');
   },
   function() {
     console.log('err');
   })
   .catch(function() {
      console.error('fetch failed');
   });
```

in console this promise looks like this

```
_bitField: 0
_fulfillmentHandler0: undefined
_promise0: undefined
_receiver0: undefined
_rejectionHandler0: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

I think that fetchAsync calls non promisifyed versions of sync and ajax calls that do not return resolve in this promise. I'm new to promises so sorry if I wrote something silly.

On promisifying backbone I found very little info in google, just several packages on npm, but I don't want to include extra packages, especcially if they are not popular.

Comment: `fetch` already returns a promise in backbone, no need to promisify it.

Comment: Also, `promisify` only works on functions that have the node function convention,

Comment: thx @BenjaminGruenbaum You're right! I found that I need to wrap jqXHR promise in Bluebird.resolve() and after that I can use it as bluebird promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BenjaminGruenbaum says in the comments

`fetch` already returns a promise in backbone, no need to promisify it.

`promisify` only works on functions that have the node function convention

however fetch returns jqXHR and I want Bluebird promise, so I need to use Bluebird.resolve() and that's it.

So I ended up with this

```
            Promise.resolve(diagram.fetch())
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log('success');
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    console.error('fetch failed');
                });
```